# Multiple touch unity mobile

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mobile, 2d

I am creating a 2d mobile game where one of the scripts uses a joystick to move and the other script lets the player shoot an object when tapping anywhere on the screen. The issue is when using the joystick it also shoots at the same time in that direction. Is there a way to separate the touches so when you use the joystick it does not immediately shoot to that direction but the player can still move and shoot anywhere at the same time?

```
Move Code
  private void Update()
    {
        Vector2 moveInput = new Vector2(joystick.Horizontal, joystick.Vertical);
        moveAmount = moveInput.normalized * speed;

    }

Shoot code
  private void Update()
    {
        Vector2 direction = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - transform.position;
        float angle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.y, direction.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle - 90, Vector3.forward);
        transform.rotation = rotation;

        if(Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            if (Time.time >= shotTime)
            {
                Instantiate(projectile, shotPoint.position, transform.rotation);
                shotTime = Time.time + timeBetweenShots;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using Input.mousePosition you'll have to use [Input.GetTouch](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetTouch.html). You can loop through it using [Input.touchCount](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-touchCount.html) to find the first touch that is not interacting with a ui element, than use that touch instead of Input.mousePosition to find the direction to shoot (or not shoot if there is no touch). To find out if a specific touch is over ui you need a reference to the scene's EventSystem (or use EventSystem.current), and use [EventSystem.IsPointerOverGameObject](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/api/UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem.html) with [Touch.fingerId](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Touch-fingerId.html).

If the joystick is not a ui element you'll need a different way to detect if the touch is over the joystick. For example you could check the pixel position, or see if the joystick itself has an "interacting fingerId". But with the assumption that the joystick is an ui element, here's one way to do what I wrote above: (untested)

```
private void Update()
{
    var eventSystem = EventSystem.current;
    
    for (var i = 0; i<Input.touchCount; i++)
    {
        var touch = Input.GetTouch(i);
        if (eventSystem.IsPointerOverGameObject(touch.fingerId)) 
        {
            continue;
        }
        
        ShootToScreenPos(Vector2 screenPos);
        break;
    }
}

private void ShootToScreenPos(Vector2 screenPos)
{
    Vector2 direction = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(screenPos) - transform.position;
    float angle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.y, direction.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle - 90, Vector3.forward);
    transform.rotation = rotation;

    if (Time.time >= shotTime)
    {
        Instantiate(projectile, shotPoint.position, transform.rotation);
        shotTime = Time.time + timeBetweenShots;
    }
}
```